# Which meaning of "as" is used in "as to" and "so as to"

Tags: american-english, british-english, so-as-to

The common word "as" can be used as preposition, adverb, conjunction etc. But when we use phrases like:-

"So as to", "as to", "as of now", "as of yet" etc.

Which meaning of "as" is being used ?

Comment: If you look up 'so as to' at [7esl.com](https://7esl.com/so-as-to/), you will see that they label the complete expression 'so as to' an _idiom_. This means that the expression uses odd definition/s for component words, strange grammar, or both. It's best to see such expressions as unitary (French would, after all, just use 'pour' here), without trying to find the nearest meaning 'as' on its own possesses. Prepositions are notoriously polysemous, and once one gets away from the central usages, probably best just seen as function words, bleached of semantic import. What does 'on' mean ...

Comment: in 'on fire', for instance?

Answer (score -2):

"As" is a filler word and slang and thus can be reformulated with more clear words in all context. Your question thus cant be answered for all cases, because the word itself has no proper definition (since its meaning is relational by history
https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=as ).

Take this few examples:
"I want to be as big as a giraffe" => "I want to be big like a giraffe"
"I want to be as big as possible" => "I want to be the biggest"
"As long as you" => "Whilst you"

Your question:
"as to" => context for giving a reason/goal (for/in/on etc)
"as of now/yet" => until now/yet

Comment: How is *as* "slang"?

Comment: Slang has the same meaning as quasi, which relates to something similar. As similarities are always more accurately definable, this is slang.

Comment: 1 You should look up the word *slang* in a dictionary. 2 I don’t see how the word *quasi* would fit there either.